# Always Statements in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am writing code for an 8-bit synchronous counter using t_flipflops with asynchronous clear. Here is my code:

```
module T_ff(CLK,E,CLEAR,T,Q);
input CLK,E,CLEAR,D;
output reg Q;

always@(posedge CLK, negedge CLEAR,E,T)
    begin:
        if(~CLEAR)
            Q<=1b'0;
        else if (E == 1)
            Q<=Q^T;
    end:
endmodule
```

However, I get an error at the `if` statement:

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at lab5.v(25) near text "if";  expecting an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword )
```

Any help?  Also, can I put `E` and `T` in the sensitivity list along with the posedge and negedge functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the colons after the begin and end.

You shouldn't put E and T into the sensitivity list.
A flipflop does something when the clock changes, or when reset.  You don't want the block to be triggered when E or T change.

```
module T_ff(CLK,E,CLEAR,T,Q);
input CLK,E,CLEAR,D;
output reg Q;

always@(posedge CLK or negedge CLEAR)
    begin
        if(~CLEAR)
            Q<=1b'0;
        else if (E == 1)
            Q<=Q^T;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use colons after begin/end keywords, you need to follow them with an identifier.  Keep in mind that this is a SystemVerilog feature (refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), Section 9.3.4 "Block Names").  For example, you could name your block `dff`:

```
module T_ff(CLK,E,CLEAR,T,Q);
input CLK,E,CLEAR,T;  // D should be T
output reg Q;

always@(posedge CLK, negedge CLEAR)
    begin: dff
        if(~CLEAR)
            Q<=1b'0;
        else if (E == 1)
            Q<=Q^T;
    end: dff
endmodule
```

Naming your blocks is optional.  Using a name after the `end` keyword is also optional.

Also, I think you should change `D` to `T` in your port declaration.  As the other Answer said, you should not use E or T in your sensitivity list.